# Textfield not updating with SaveAs dialog

Tags: asp.net

For some reason, when I show the SaveAs dialog, my Checksum box never gets updated.  However, if I comment out the Content-Disposition header code below then everything works fine.  Any ideas?

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checksumField.Text = String.Empty;

    FileInfo filename = this.CreateFileInfoFromInput();

    if (!filename.Exists)
    {
        tableField.Focus();
        tableField.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }

    this.SaveFile(filename);
    checksumField.Text = GetChecksum(filename);
}

private FileInfo CreateFileInfoFromInput()
{
    /* blah */
    return new FileInfo(blah);
}

private string GetChecksum(FileInfo filename)
{
    return "test";
}

private void SaveFile(FileInfo fileName)
{
    // Clear old headers
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = false;

    // Set the ContentType and Headers
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.Name);  //  <<<---- FAILING RIGHT HERE
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileName.Length.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); 

    // Send data
    Response.TransmitFile(fileName.FullName);
}
```

Comment: You are shortcircuiting the Page's lifecycle using this code. What is the purpose of your savefile method?? I don't understand. The user upload a file and should receive it in return?

Comment: The user enters in a 2 character ID and the server should return a table file to the user.  SendFile would probably be a better name for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are short-circuiting the the page lifecycle.

Instead of letting the page update itself and render to the response stream, you inject the file in the response

My advise would be to follow these steps :

1. create a simple handler (ashx file that will server the file based on a ID)
2. Change your page to produce a link to this handler (or a script that will open this url)

When the user submit an ID, generate the file as you did (hope the process is short), update your textbox (this should work as you did) and add the link to the handler file servicing.

Just beware of the security implication. Don't blindly send the file specified in the url (to avoid file path injection).

Comment: I'm not exactly proficient with ASP.NET; however, why are there numerous tutorials doing it the same way I'm doing it?  Are you suggesting that everyone is short-circuiting the page lifecycle?

It just seems like there should be a simpler way than this, but I may be wrong.

Comment: All tutorial you will see will serve a file. But not serve a file AND update control values.

Comment: Is there any way I can just call the handler without returning a link?  I need a SaveAs dialog to show (I can't just use a link).  I see you mentioned a script, but is there a function call that will basically call ProcessRequest()?

Comment: In this case, don't output a link, but a script that will do a `window.open` on the handler. Look at all websites that offer file download. All of them have a "download" page that will eventually fire the actual download.

Comment: Any way to do it without opening a new window? Sorry, but my boss wants this to be as simple as possible. 1. User enters ID 2. User clicks Download button 3. SaveAs Dialog opens and user saves file 4. Checksum for file shows in textbox on page 5. Repeat if user wants to download next table.

Comment: window.open won't open a new window if the target is to be downloaded